# AWSIotDevice.get() hung forever

Tags: mqtt, paho, aws-iot

I'm calling this code inside a rest service (implement in Spring Boot server.)
First call is running OK.
( client was init correctly, and getting the device shadow state correctly )
When I'm running the same service for the second time - the code `device.get()` is simply hanging on and suspend the thread forever.

I'm working with

com.amazonaws:aws-iot-device-sdk-java:1.3.6

org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.2

This is my code:

```
AWSIotMqttClient awsIotClient = awsIotService.initClient();
AWSIotDevice device = new AWSIotDevice(deviceName);
        try {
            awsIotClient.attach(device);

            if(awsIotClient.getConnectionStatus()== AWSIotConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED) {
                awsIotClient.connect(5000,true);
            }
            // Retrieve updated document from the shadow
            String shadowState = device.get();  // =>Suspended
```

Here is my Client connection code: ( which is connected successfully )

```
KeyStorePasswordPair pair = getKeyStorePasswordPair(certificateFile, privateKeyFile);
awsIotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, pair.keyStore, pair.keyPassword);
awsIotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(60000);
awsIotClient.setNumOfClientThreads(5);
awsIotClient.setMaxConnectionRetries(5);
```

And BTW the same happens in the second call to: `device.update(jsonState)`